# Merging vertices in Blender breaks the UV

Tags: uv, edit-mode, vertices, uv-image-editor

So, the problem is pretty much self-explanatory and obvious on the screenshots. When I merge vertices (in this case using merge by distance but it also happens with merge to first/last:
[image]

[image]

Sometimes I'm manually welding/merging vertices using Merge to first/Last and this things happens again. If I dissolve a middle edge instead of merging vertices (like in some cases is possible) - there's no problem.

I'm coming from 3ds Max and there's nothing like this, if you weld vertices - the UV corresponds to what happens in the viewport.

Is there a way to avoid this? Even if it's a process with a number of steps that can be automated using a script? This is really frustrating and every time I merge I need to go to the UV and fix it.

P.S: This happens both with UV sync ON and OFF

**UPDATE**

This is a screenshot side by side of the UV and the corresponding part of the object

[image]

Comment: did u try uv unwrap again?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the wireframe in the viewport, before and after welding the vertices?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this is just how it works. It's ill advised to continue manipulating geometry after you've UV unwrapped an object. You leave that until you're done editing or sculpting.

This is just going from everything I've picked up from when I was learning Blender to begin with, and I never challenged it. I never knew differently. What you're asking might simply be impossible, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Merge by Distance doesn't update UV, however, dissolving does. Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Chris: No, unwraping is not an option. @Alexandre Marcati Sure, I'll update the post in 2 days (I'm out of town). Onyx: I agree that Unwraping should be last, but the geometry comes from another software with Unwrap that can't be changed. It is possible in 3ds Max, but I'm not sure if it is in Blender. Markus von Broady: This happens after merging. I'l post a .gif file to show what happens. In the screenshot above, where there are holes, the two surrounding selected vertices are actually a single vertex on the geometry.

Comment: Well you just answered your own question. The two surrounding vertices are the same vertex, meaning the hole in the uv is a face that existed before but ceased to exist after merging... What did you expect to happen in the uv layout? You just have to stitch the vertices in the uvs aswell.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati Yes, but this should happen automatically instead of me having to go to the UV and stitching everything back together. If I use merge by distance in the UV sometimes it merges the wrong vertices because the distance is different whereas if it merged automatically when merging the verts in the 3D object in the viewport - there won't be a problem. At least that's how it works in 3ds Max and if there's no way for this to happen in Blender then I guess I'll have to think of one and write a script for it :)

Comment: You're right, it should stitch the vertices in the UV layout too.